# send request to FCM for push notification and get ("MissingRegistration")?

Tags: .net, json, firebase, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send request to FCM/firease Cloud Messaging for push notification to android device but every time in get ("MissingRegistration").
I can't the correct format of json to push notification. 
This is the json format how I Sent

```
{ "registration_ids": [ "/*FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()*/" ]   , "notification" : { "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark" , "text": "5 to 1" }   }
```

I need for all any a idea.

Comment: do you send `Content-type:application/json` and `Authorization:key=YOUR_KEY` as headers in the request?

Comment: Could you confirm that you are using the actual Instance ID token in place of /*FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()*/?

Comment: Yes, I used same ID token in firebase console to send notification and it sent to the device.

Comment: When I but Content-type:appliction/json,I get Exception Bad Request.So I but it "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 ".

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads)

Or try this json format :--

```
{ "registration_ids": [ "/*FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()*/" ], "data": {"contentTitle":"content title GCM", "message": "some test message"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found solution for this problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551245/3241790). By using anonymous types then convert it to Json by JavaScriptSerializer.