# How to send notification from C# Console application

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create console application which is used to send notifications to different mobile devices via Goolge Firebase Notifications,

I have seen the code from link [Send push to Android by C# using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412963/send-push-to-android-by-c-sharp-using-fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging)

I am getting internal server error with status code 500

```
try{
    string url = @"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

    string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + "This is the message" + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
    var data = new
    {
        to = deviceId,
        notification = new
        {
            body = "This is the message",
            title = "This is the title"

        }
    };
    string jsonss = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonss);              
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                {
                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(sResponseFromServer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.Message);
    {
        var sss = ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            var ss = ex.InnerException;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Technically, a HTTP 500 is not your fault (it's an Internal Server Error after all :) ). However it is not impossible the internal error be caused by your actions. Also, is there anything the server's response body?

Comment: A server 500 is an internal server error, but is most likely caused by invalid data being sent from the client.

Comment: Yes, Duston is right,
 I am using wrong value in variable 'applicationID'
I am using mobilesdk_app_id value instead of api_key current key thats why it is giving 500 error

Thanks Json, Francis Lord  for your efforts :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

Here is the code to send notification using C#, I have made it working

```
 WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                        tRequest.Method = "post";
                        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                        var objNotification = new
                        {
                            to = notification.DeviceToken,
                            data = new
                            {
                                title = notification.NotificationTitle,
                                body = notification.NotificationBody
                            }
                        };
                        string jsonNotificationFormat = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objNotification);

                        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonNotificationFormat);
                        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverKey));
                        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
                        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
                        {
                            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                            {
                                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                {
                                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                                    {
                                        String responseFromFirebaseServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                                        FCMResponse response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FCMResponse>(responseFromFirebaseServer);
                                        if (response.success == 1)
                                        {
                                            new NotificationBLL().InsertNotificationLog(dayNumber, notification, true);
                                        }
                                        else if (response.failure == 1)
                                        {
                                            new NotificationBLL().InsertNotificationLog(dayNumber, notification, false);
                                            sbLogger.AppendLine(string.Format("Error sent from FCM server, after sending request : {0} , for following device info: {1}", responseFromFirebaseServer, jsonNotificationFormat));

                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

Here is class FCMResponse used in this code to store response sent  from FMServer

```
 public class FCMResponse
{
    public long multicast_id { get; set; }
    public int success { get; set; }
    public int failure { get; set; }
    public int canonical_ids { get; set; }
    public List<FCMResult> results { get; set; }
}
  public class FCMResult
{
    public string message_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is FCMResult in this case? Can you please share FCMResult class code too please?

Comment: Hi @MudasserHassan I've updated the answer adding FCMResult class

Comment: and now FCMResult?

Comment: Now you have it, @MudasserHassan

Comment: FRMResult class code is still missing. Can you please add?

Comment: @MudasserHassan class FCMResult  is added

Comment: Good job, it can also be used in Xamarin to send push without firebase console

Comment: I am getting Excepation at "WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse()" this Line Unauthorized. How to solve this?

Comment: I am new to C# world, can you tell me from where to get device token ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **Duston** is right, I am using wrong value in variable '**applicationID**'

Actually I am using mobilesdk_app_id value instead of api_key current key thats why it is giving 500 error

Now it is working fine :)

Thanks Json, Francis Lord for your efforts :)