# Push message not getting from server

Tags: c#, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am an android developer, Now I am integrating push notification on my android application. Now I am having a problem,

When I send message from firebase I am getting the push message. But when message sending from backend There is some error. On backend they are getting

"`{"multicast_id":4781872077855061201,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}`"

Is this is backend issue? ON backend they are using the correct `Server key` and `Sender ID`  On this [C# FCM for Android Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712221/c-sharp-fcm-for-android-push-notification) They are telling like,

> I found the error. As a back-end developer I worked on C# part only.
>   There is one more step to be done from mobile application side. Mobile
>   app should allow receiving messages from list of Sender Ids so the one
>   that I use in my C# code must be allowed from mobile app side. Once I
>   did that it worked