# Push notifications from server

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to send a notification from an Console App to an android device I am using the following code:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string applicationId = "applicationId";
        string senderId = "senderId";
        string deviceId = "deviceId";
        string message = "TestMessage";

        var x = new AndroidFCMPushNotificationStatus();
        var response = x.SendNotification(applicationId, senderId, deviceId, message);
        Console.WriteLine(response);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class AndroidFCMPushNotificationStatus
    {
        public string SendNotification(string applicationID, string senderId, string deviceId, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                var data = new
                {
                    to = deviceId,
                    notification = new
                    {
                        body = message,
                        title = message,

                    },
                    priority = "high"
                };

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            string sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            return (sResponseFromServer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

from [Push Notification C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412963/send-push-to-android-by-c-sharp-using-fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging).

I created a firebase console project and from the project settings, from the tab Cloud Messaging I got the Server Key and Sender Id (in code they are the applicationId and senderId). I also got my device Id from an app I downloaded to my mobile, where it gives me a string under the label Android Device Id.

However I get the message error:InvalidRegistration.

I am pretty new to this and I think I am missing something.

- Is the above code supposed to work and whenever I run the program I should get a notification on my phone?
- Should I do anything to allow this notifications to my mobile? I haven't configured anything on my device.
- The idea is to pack this code in a service and whenever something is happening on the server I want to use this code in order to inform
  my device. Is this the correct way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error:InvalidRegistration` means that the deviceId (also called Registration token) is wrong.

> Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server.
>   Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives
>   from registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add
>   additional characters.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes

check that you are reading the correct token:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#retrieve-the-current-registration-token