# Firebase Cloud Messaging using Web API C#

Tags: c#, android, firebase, asp.net-web-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am referencing from the following link to achieve push notification, but how can I get the device Id? I put my mobile MMID as device ID but it's not working. Do I need to register my android mobile on firebase or need to install firebase package to get the registerID?

[Send push to Android by C# using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412963/send-push-to-android-by-c-sharp-using-fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging/39778368#39778368)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `deviceId` refers to the [Registration Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials):

> An ID generated by the FCM SDK for each client app instance. Required for single device and device group messaging. Note that registration tokens must be kept secret.

which is generated on the client side, in your case, Android. You'll have to [Setup your Android App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) to generate the token and receive messages. Also see the [possible duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671576/4625829).

Comment: Thanks AL for your suggestion. Appreciate It !! :)