# how to make a web application in .NET send notifications to firebase?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) to use FCM and send notifications.But my problem is I want to have a web app in .NET in which I send notifications or messages to firebase.

The idea is to send notifications through a web-app to firebase and this will be responsible for sending to a mobile device

Does anyone know what I should do to be able to do this?
Are there any tutorials where they can do this?

Comment: I did a search on ".net web app to firebase" and got lots of interesting hints. How is this question not handled by those resources?

Comment: the information on the database and not on how to send notifications to a firebase server

Comment: Perhaps of interest: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: i follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412963/send-push-to-android-by-c-sharp-using-fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging  and i solve!